# For loop in Javascript to display the books;

Tags: javascript, json

```
        "Pascal" : [
              {"Name": "Pascal made simple","price":"700"},
              {"Name": "Guide to pascal","price":"400"},
              {"Name": "Pascal for all","price":"500"}],


        "Scala" :  [
              {"Name":"Scala for Dummies","price":"1000"},
              {"Name":"Scala in Depth","Price":"1300"}]
```

please help me to Write a for-loop in javascript to display the books for Pascal as an HTML table.

Comment: Please post any code showing what you have tried to solved the problem. You may also want to review these other [5000 similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+json+table) for ideas and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over the books and add them as html:

```
function booksToTable(books) {
    var html = ['<table>'];
    for (var i = 0, l = books.length; i < l; i++) {
        var book = books[i];
        html.push('<tr><td>' + book.Name + '</td><td>' + book.price + '</td></tr>');
    }
    html.push('</table>');
    return html.join('\n');
}

document.write(booksToTable(input.Pascal));
```